# What does a path with no repeatiting vertices represent in a undirected graph?

Tags: graph, path

I recently run into stuff related to an undirected  graph.
I have some questions, that when answered I think I could prove my ideas.

In an undirected connected graph, between two vertices `a` and `b`, there are paths connecting these vertices. In this graph, each edge and node have unique identifiers.
When I compute paths between `a` and `b`, I think i will get a path in which no edge appears twice if I don't allow traversing a same vertex twice.
My question is that what does a non-repeated path represent? does such a non-repeated path has a meaning?

Could anyone familiar with graph theory could give me a hint, or answer?
what is the meaning of such paths?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously, if there's any path between two vertices, then there's also a simple path between them too. That is simple (i.e. non-repeated) paths are "good", and paths "with repetitions" are just simple paths with some overhead (cycles). That means that simple paths are the most "interesting" paths. Isn't it enough?

Comment: user4419802: thank you. that is exactly I am trying to ensure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the question you asked if it is true that "I think i will get a path in which no edge appears twice if I don't allow traversing a same vertex twice".

This is true. for a path to have a cycle in it it must go through (at least) one node (vertex) twice.

The meaning of a simple path is entirely dependant on what you are looking for. If the weight of each edge is positive, then finding a lightest path works only on simple paths.

Comment: Thank you. with those comments, I confirm my assumption is true.